Error when running Spring Boot app with embedded Tomcat
I have the following configuration for a Springboot application:
DemoApplication.kt
package com.planes.planesserver

import org.springframework.boot.autoconfigure.SpringBootApplication
import org.springframework.boot.runApplication

@SpringBootApplication
class DemoApplication

fun main(args: Array<String>) {
     runApplication<DemoApplication>(*args)
}

build.gradle.kts
import org.jetbrains.kotlin.gradle.tasks.KotlinCompile


plugins {
    id("war")
    id("org.springframework.boot") version "3.2.0"
    id("io.spring.dependency-management") version "1.1.4"
    kotlin("jvm") version "1.9.21"
    kotlin("plugin.spring") version "1.9.20"
    kotlin("plugin.jpa") version "1.9.20"
    id("org.flywaydb.flyway") version "7.15.0"
}

group = "com.planes.planesserver"
version = "0.0.1-SNAPSHOT"
java {
     sourceCompatibility = JavaVersion.VERSION_17
}

repositories {
    mavenCentral()
}

dependencies {
//here list of dependencies
}

tasks.withType<Test> {
    useJUnitPlatform()
}

tasks.withType<Jar> {
    duplicatesStrategy = DuplicatesStrategy.EXCLUDE

    manifest {
         attributes["Main-Class"] = "com.planes.planesserver.DemoApplication"
    }
}


tasks.withType<KotlinCompile> {
    kotlinOptions {
        freeCompilerArgs = listOf("-Xjsr305=strict")
        jvmTarget = "17"
    }
}

springBoot {
    mainClass.set( "com.planes.planesserver.DemoApplication")
}

//other stuff

I am deploying with the bootJar  gradle task. When trying to run the jar with java -jar I get the error: main class cannot be found or loaded.
I unpacked the jar archive. Under BOOT-INF/classes/com/planes/planesserver there exists the file DemoApplication.class as well as the DemoApplicationKt.class
Can anyone give me a hint in the right direction ?

When you run java -jar JVM looks into jar file and search for a file MANIFEST.MF in META-INF directory. This file contains information about main class - the class who's method main will be executed.
Here is an example content of MANIFEST.MF
Manifest-Version: 1.0
Main-Class: org.springframework.boot.loader.launch.JarLauncher
Start-Class: example.HelloSpringApplication
Spring-Boot-Version: 3.2.2
Spring-Boot-Classes: BOOT-INF/classes/
Spring-Boot-Lib: BOOT-INF/lib/
Spring-Boot-Classpath-Index: BOOT-INF/classpath.idx
Spring-Boot-Layers-Index: BOOT-INF/layers.idx
Build-Jdk-Spec: 21
Implementation-Title: hello-spring
Implementation-Version: 1.3.0

If there is no such file JVM does not know where it should find main class and you get this message. Simply having a class in classpath is not enough. Look if you have such file inside jar. If not it is something wrong with your build file
As you can see in this example the main class is springframework's JarLauncher, in your build file you changed it to your class. It will work for ordinary Java application but not in SpringBoot. Delete lines
springBoot {
    mainClass.set( "com.planes.planesserver.DemoApplication")
}

and now it will work

Yes. I have it. I will check again against your example to see if the values are ok.

This worked. I had to additionally delete the line defining the main class under tasks.withType and after that it worked.
